# How to click the Play button of the video in Hooktube with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, youtube

Could someone help me how to click play button using hooktube with JavaScript?

As an example I have this url
https://hooktube.com/watch?v=wMGkB_t4BqA

I tried these options but to no avail :(

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button')[0].click();
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play()
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].pause()
```

Thank you all for the attention.

Answer (score 3):

You can click the play button as follows:

```js
document.querySelector("#movie_player > div.ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay > button").click()
```

You can find any selector for a specific element on any site by:

- Opening chrome devtools using `Ctrl + Shift + I`.
- Using the element picker to select an element on the page.

[image]

- Right click on the now highlighted element in devtools.
- And finally click copy > copy selector.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that the player is within an `<iframe>` which contains even another `<iframe>`.
To get an element within an *iframe* element, you need to use something like this:

```
let iframe1 = document.getElementById("player-obj");
let iframe2 = iframe1.contentWindow.document.getElementById("player");
iframe2.querySelector("#movie_player > div.ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay > button").click()
```